# How to obtain a crisp maybe vector graphics format image from a symbollic expression

Tags: graphics, export, image-processing, import, image

[**EDIT :** The image should stay within Mathematica so I can not use `Export["file.svg", expression]` as `Import` does not support svg files]

Consider the expression $1+x^2$. One can convert this expression into an image using

```
ImportByteArray@ExportByteArray[1 + x^2, "PNG"]
```

or

```
ImportString@ExportString[1 + x^2, "PNG"]
```

However, the image quality is bad (pixeled). Changing "PNG" to "EPS" leads to a full black image (or white depending on the stylesheet) and changing "PNG" to "PDF" also leads to an image with bad quality (pixeled).

My solution was this rather complicated code that gives a nice image

```
Style[Text[1 + x^2], FontSize -> 100] // Graphics // Image // 
ExportByteArray[#, "PDF"] & // ImportByteArray // First // 
Image[#, ImageSize -> 50] &
```

(`ImageCrop` in the above code could also be useful)

But that code looks like it depends a lot on the size of the expression. For example changing 1+x^2 with `Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, x*Log[x]/(x^2 + 4), 2]` shows the wrong output image when compared with the actual output.

(`Pane` could be useful here but it required some fiddling around)

I suppose that a solution for this is to clip the image around the expression. How could one do that ?

Are there other ways to obtain nice images from an expression ?

The two test expressions:

- `1 + x^2`
- `Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, x*Log[x]/(x^2 + 4), 2]`

**EDIT**

Using

```
ImportByteArray[
  x^2 + 1 // ExportByteArray[#, "PDF"] &, {"PDF", 
   "PageGraphics"}] // First
```

I got a nice image but it is a `Graphics` object. I did not find a way to turn that into a crisp image with the same size. A solution that requires adjusting image resolution and image size would be too tedious for me.

**EDIT2:**

There is a resource function [SVGImport](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SVGImport/) by a Wolfram research member that allows importing svg files using `ExternalEvaluate` and Python (so it might not work if Python is not configured to work with Mathematica). The resulting object is a `Graphics` object. The method seems to use PDF as an intermediate so I do not know if there is a benefit from exporting and importing as SVG rather than PDF.

Using `Magnify` with either the PDF or SVG method gave some nice results.

Comment: What do you want to do with the image?  Do you need a bit map or can you target application handle vector graphics (e.g. SVG)?

Comment: @mikado Hi I want the image to stay inside Mathematica which is why I used `ExportByteArray` rather than `Export`. I wish I could use SVG with `Import` or `ImportByteArray` but it seems Mathematica does not support importing this format.

Comment: @mikado there is a resource function [SVGImport](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SVGImport/) from a wolfram research member for importing SVG files.

Comment: @mikado that said it uses `ExternalEvaluate` to evaluate to `Python` so it might not work if Pythonis not set up to work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must rasterize the expression with a better resolution. The following creates a tiny picture of the expression

```
ImportByteArray@
 ExportByteArray[Rasterize[1 + x^2, ImageResolution -> 1000], "PNG"]
```

[image]

From the tiny picture you can not judge the resolution. However, if you enlarge the picture by click and drag, you see that the picture has a good resolution:

[image]

Comment: Very nice thank you. I did not know how to change the resolution. For large expressions I had to decrease the resolution like `ImportByteArray@ExportByteArray[Rasterize[Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, x*Log[x]/(x^2 + 4), 2], ImageResolution -> 100], "PNG"]`. I guess I could try to fit a curve to find the maximal resolution given the `LeafCount` of an expression. I will accept your answer if I do not see any answer that does not involve choosing the resolution manually (maybe one that uses a vector format).

Comment: On my computer (Linux) the image was not tiny so I did not have to click and drag.